# Get sum of column using FileMaker PHP Api

Tags: php, sql, api, sum, filemaker

I have a tablo as shown below.

[image]

```
SELECT SUM (People) FROM "Booking" WHERE TourDate = 3/01/2017
```

I can print 40 when using this sql query on FileMaker. I want to get sum of the column "People" using FileMaker PHP Api. So far I have written this:

```
include("filemaker.php");   
$date = "3/01/2017";   
$fm = new FileMaker('filename', 'hostname', 'admin','passw0rd');  
$findCommand = $fm->newFindCommand("Bookings");   
$findCommand->addFindCriterion("TourDate", $date);   
$result = $findCommand->execute();   
$records = $result->getRecords();
```

First time I am using FM PHP Api. I don't know how to proceed from here. I would appreciate any suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileMaker PHP API does not support ExecuteSQL and does not have a function to sum a field across the found set

The easiest way is to use a standard PHP array_sum() on the result of your getRecords()